# how to configure system to use git via an ssh reverse tunnel / proxy?

Tags: git, ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

*Environment:*
My localhost has access to my VPN.
My remotehost needs to access the VPN via my localhost.
I can only ssh from localhost to remotehost.  I have setup a tunnel to access the shell on my remotehost.

I have ssh setup from localhost to remotehost using keys and without password prompt.

```
ssh -X remotehost -L 5901:localhost:5901
```

This allows me to run VNC from localhost to access my remotehost.

*Problem:*
My remotehost has git repos which need to be updated, but via the localhost's VPN. i.e. when I perform on the remotehost a `git pull` command, it will access the VPN git repository via the tunnel created from localhost.

I have read about `ssh -R` and ssh .config having a ProxyCommand, but putting it altogether is a mess.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `RemoteForward` option in your `.ssh/config`

```
HOST remoteHost
   hostname remotehost.somewhere.com
   user <username>
   RemoteForward 127.0.0.1:2022 <VPN-GitHost>:22
```

This publishes the port 22 from your VPN to your remoteHost but changes the port number to 2022.

On your remote host you can use that port via ssh (and also git) like

```
ssh myuser@localhost -p 2022
```

Or edit the .ssh/config on the remote host

```
HOST VPN-gitHost
   hostname localhost
   port 2022
```

Then your `git pull` should work without any modifications

Comment: jeb, this worked!  Thank you for the explanation too.  I'm being prompted for my passphrase when I git pull now.  The IdentityFile directive with and without the ForwardAgent isn't working.   That's the last piece of my puzzle.

Comment: All working with ForwardAgent employed in the config on localhost.

Comment: @Harry For a different question you should ask a new one. The comment section is not appropriate for this